# A word to describe the class to which synthetic and natural belong

Tags: single-word-requests

What word would you use to ask if something is synthetic or natural?

> What was the ____ of the materials in this shirt?

Should mean I am asking if its made from natural or synthetic materials.

Comment: _What was the material his shirt was made of?_

Answer (score 1):

**Composition**

> The nature or attributes of its constituents, as in a chemical composition.

Answer (score -1):

I think perhaps the word I'm looking for is provenance.

> **Provenance**
>
> the place of origin or earliest known history of something.

Comment: Can't you just ask *What kind of material (or perhaps fabric) is/was this shirt made out of?* For example, cotton is natural, rayon is man-made, and nylon is synthetic.

Comment: Place of origin or earliest known history of something (say, "an orange rug of Iranian provenance") is one thing; whether the thing is made of natural or synthetic material is quite another.